# How do I access template content in the same "event" as it gets visible in Polymer

Tags: templates, polymer

Let me try and stub out my question

```
<polymer-element name="my-element">
    <template>
        <template if="{{show}}">
            <my-other-element id="elementWithUnexposedInternals"></my-other-element>
        </template>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            show: false,
            showChanged: function{
                this.$.elementWithUnexposedInternals.someProperty = true;
            }
        });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

It seems my-other-element is not accessible in the this.$ line as the template has not rendered it yet.

How can I get around this "order" issue?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you have two problems. One is that the element isn't rendered yet, and the other is that the element will **never** get added to `this.$`, which is only populated with the element's *static contents*:

https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/polymer/polymer.html#automatic-node-finding

You can work around the second issue by adding a static container and using querySelector:

```
<polymer-element name="my-element">
  <template>
    <div id="container>
      <template if="{{show}}">
        <my-other-element id="elementWithUnexposedInternals"></my-other-element>
      </template>
    </div>
  ...

var el = this.$.container.querySelector('#elementWithUnexposedInternals');
```

As for the timing. In Polymer 0.5, data binding updates take place with microtask timing (after the current event handler, and before the next event is processed). As you're seeing, the changed handler is getting called before the data bound template has stamped its contents.

You should be able to solve this by delaying accessing the element with `async`. Combining these two fixes, you get:

```
        showChanged: function(){
          this.async(function() {
            var myEl = 
      this.$.container.querySelector("#elementWithUnexposedInternals");
            myEl.someProp = true;
          });
        },
```

`setTimeout(function, 0);` would probably work, too -- all you need to do is delay a single cycle in the event loop. But `async` is more idiomatic in Polymer (plus, it invokes the callback with `this` bound to the custom element instance, which is handy).

Working example here: http://jsbin.com/gicado/1/edit?html,output

Answer (score 0):

You can set value for 'show' in 'domReady' event listener.